# How to export raw data feeds from Google Big Query to R servers in a CSV tabular format?

Tags: python, json, csv, google-bigquery

I tried using the Python code mentioned in the link https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/exporting-data-from-bigquery

However, on running the code it says that since the table has a nested schema it does not allow it to be exported as a CSV.

My objective is to extract the raw daily feeds from the Big Query environment to local R Server environment in order to do custom statistics on the clickstream.

Please help me out!

Comment: You need to flatten the results. My suggestion would be to find a query that works for you in the BigQuery browser (where results are flatten by default). Then save it as a view in that screen and use that view in your code. If it doesn't work, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested or repeated data cannot be exported to CSV.  You could instead export your BigQuery table to JSON.  The python sample you were following should work, you'll just need to add a `destinationFormat` to your extract job's configuration, like at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/exporting-data-from-bigquery#extractconfig

```
'destinationFormat': 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON'
```

Documentation on this parameter: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.extract.destinationFormat